# Box of gold problem

Tags: probability

The following question was posted on a social networking site. There was a disagreement as to the correct answer. Please provide an answer to help resolve the disagreement.

> There are three closed boxes. One has a large pile of gold in it and the other two are empty. You get to choose a box. After choosing, one of the boxes you did not choose, one without gold, is taken away. Now you have the option to stay with your original choice or switch to the other remaining box. Do you stay or switch?

To be clear, you would favor the box of gold.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: For more posts about this question please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=monty%20hall).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the right terms to use. I appreciate your help very much.